# Android/PHP/APACHE - POST method doesn't work only with HTTPRequest from Android

Tags: java, php, android, apache, post

I've got a problem. I configured myself a Debian server with an Apache/MySQL/PHPMyAdmin and PHP5. Everything is working very well when I do some test from my browser on my PC.

But this server will be used as a Web Service for my Android Application. And when I try to send my POST HTTPRequest from my Android app, the server doesn't read any POST data.

This is my HTTPRequest code:

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(AbstractServiceKeys.URL);
    try {
        MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

        for(int index=0; index < params.size(); index++) {
            if(params.get(index).getName().equalsIgnoreCase("avatar")) {
                entity.addPart(params.get(index).getName(), new FileBody( new File (params.get(index).getValue())) );
            } else {
                entity.addTextBody(params.get(index).getName(), params.get(index).getValue());
            }
        }
        entity.addTextBody("lang", Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
        httpPost.setEntity(entity.build());
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        .....
```

To see if datas have been correctly sent, I do this on the PHP server side :

```
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

It answer me :

```
Array()
Array()
```

I know that the problem comes from my server because I tested this on an another server from a friend. But now, I don't know what to do.

Please help mens !

**[EDIT] :** I found the problem but I can't understand why it didn't work before.
My URL was :

```
 http: //[server_domain_name.com]/index.php
```

I change it to :

```
 http: //[server_ip]/index.php
```

And it worked. I don't understand. It's really strange...

Comment: If the program comes from the server why did you post the android code instead of the server?

Comment: The server code is only : print_r($_POST); IT CAN'T BE WRONG ! :)

Comment: Quoting you... "I know that the problem comes from my server". And there is no need for caps. We can all read lowercase here.

Comment: Yes sorry for uppercase... I think it comes from the apache configuration but I can't find what I need to do anywhere I search.

Comment: That can be introduced if a proxy somewhere changes the post to a get omitting the content.

Comment: Can you post your apache configuration? And how is PHP setup, CGI, or mod_php?